# To get the custom field value form the post

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields

i have got the post thumbnail and post content in a page by the below code

```
                <?php
            $post_types = array('a', 'b','p','d','f');//post type names
            foreach( $post_types as $post_type) {
            // The Query
            $the_query = new WP_Query( array(
             'post_type' => $post_type,
             'orderby' => 'post_date',
             'order' => 'DESC'
            ));

            while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
                  <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { 
                        the_post_thumbnail();
                    }
                  ?>

            <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php }?>
```

Now i want to get the custom field value form the corresponding posts.

Answer (score 1):

Use [get_post_meta($post_id, $key, $single)](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) to retrieve either a single key value or the entire list of key/value pairs (as an array).

This function always returns an array (even when `$key` is specified and the array only contains a single value) unless the `$single` argument is `true`.

```
<?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ): ?>
        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
        <?php $my_key = get_post_meta($post->id, 'my_key', true); ?>
        <?php if(!empty($my_key)): ?>
            <?php echo $my_key; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: I have a custom field name "post_img" and i want get the value of each individual post, if the pot have the value otherwise not

Comment: Then assign the returned value and check if the value is set. `$value = get_post_meta(...); if(!empty($value)) { /* do stuff */ }`

Answer (score 1):

Use this (inside your `while` loop) :

```
echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'post_img', true);
```